# Hosting Classic ASP with ms access application on bluemix

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, ibm-cloud, web-hosting

I have website developed in classic asp and ms access is back-end.
It is currently hosted in a desktop (IIS) that I am using as server.
Now I am planning to move this hosting into Bluemix.

My doubts:

1) Is it possible to move this classic asp - ms access application to bluemix.

2) Can we have database(ms access) in bluemix itself or still we have to keep it separate desktop.

3) If we can keep ms access in bluemix itself how should i change the connection string.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if BlueMix supports classic asp, then yes, you can host it there, but that's a question you should ask them directly. If they support .NET hosting, then chances are they support classic asp, as classic asp is already baked into IIS, it's just a feature that needs to be enabled. so to answer your questions above:

1) you can only really verify this from them or if you find someone on here that has personal experience with them

2) you will be able to put the DB on whatever hosting service you choose, just stick it in a folder off of your root web folder, change the permissions so people can't just download it, and you'll be good to go. Of course, this all depends if they have the proper driver installed, but chances are pretty good they do, but another thing you'd want to verify w/ them

3) depending on what method you're using, you may only have to change the path to the database. if you're using ODBC, you shouldn't have anything to change if you keep the settings the same

I would contact them and ask them if they support classic asp hosting with MS Access, they should be able to give you that info immediately.

Comment: Thanks Josh for your detailed explanation